# how to transfer and use a lot of parameters of different types via function argument?

Tags: c#

Somewhere inside my function I need to do something like that:

```
        smsg["isin"].set(ii.ISIN);
        smsg["client_code"].set(Constants.CLIENT_CODE);
        smsg["type"].set(1);
        smsg["dir"].set(order.Operation == Side.Buy ? 1 : 2);
        smsg["amount"].set(order.Lots);
        smsg["price"].set(textPrice);
        smsg["ext_id"].set(0);
```

`set` method has a lot of overloads it can accept `int`, `string`, `boolean`, `DateTime` etc. totally about 15 methods.

**After refactoring** I decided function to use just list of parameters ignoring other variables `order` `ii` etc. The problem is that I don't know how can I transfer this parameters via function arguments

```
    public uint ExecuteTransaction(Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        ....
        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            smsg[parameter.Key].set(parameter.Value);  // compile time error!
        }
```

Compiler doesn't know which overload to use and so I have such error:

```
The best overloaded method match has some invalid arguments
```

My Dictionary contains appropiate value for each parameter. So boolean parameters contain boolean value etc. That's why I declared Dictionary to contain general type `object`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the type of that dictionary Dictionary<string, object>

Comment: @EsaLakaniemi added to description. yes Dictionary stores `int` `boolean` `DateTime` etc. So I have to use object.

Comment: I suppose that the data type of `parameter.Value` is `object` and you don't have an overload that accepts an object value.

Comment: @Steve that's right! `parameter.Value` is declared as object. But at runtime it has appropiate type - boolean int etc.

Comment: Did you try to write a set(object) method and in that check for the type of the object?

Comment: `set` is from library. i don't have access to this code.

Comment: Convert the "object" to a value that the set-method can handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement the set(object value) method which will determine parameter type and call typed set(T value). This is only way to use set in this maner.

Upd: if you haven't access to set as it a library you can write extension method

```
public static class Ext
{
  public static void set(this YOUR_LIB_TYPE lib, object value)
  {
    if(value is int)
    {
      lib.set((int) value);
    }
    else if(value is string)
    {
      lib.set((string) value);
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: please investigate the extension example

Comment: ok but I don't know if I should use it as my code is very time-sensitive having so many tests scare me.

Comment: But I don't know an other way to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can...

1. Modify the `set` to accept an object parameter and let the **class** manage the types.
2. Set in your `foreach` block the logic.

Example:

```
foreach (var parameter in parameters)         
{             
    // int example
    if (parameter.Value as int? != null)
        smsg[parameter.Key].set((int)parameter.Value);  // No error!         
}
```

Comment: The cast to int? from int is hi cost, isn't it?

Comment: not only the readable, the "as int?" will unbox + cast the original int instead of the type check in " is int"